# Yii Framework appears to send headers in GET response

Tags: php, yii, http-headers

I have a piece of code that has stopped working as I am developing it (but has worked before) . It sends a few headers and then serves an image with `readfile()`.

Here is my action:

```
public function actionShowMediaFile2() {
    if (headers_sent()) { 
        ...
```

In other words, the very first thing in my action is `headers_sent()` and this returns **true**.

Indeed, looking at the GET response in Firebug, there are several headers there. This prevents my sending my own headers and also seems to frustrate the `readfile()`.

My questions:

1.- Does Yii Framework send headers autonomously?

2.- If so, how do I prevent this?

3.- Or is this perhaps not Yii-related?

Here are the headers that appear to be generated autonomously by Yii:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sun, 28 Oct 2012 10:59:05 GMT
Server: Apache
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Length: 22
Keep-Alive: timeout=2, max=99
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/html
```

Checking with Fiddler, the server response appears to be: ���?�P�����k�[��� This is meaningless to me ...

Comment: `Content-Length: 22` - clearly something is getting printed before your code, possibly BOM markers, whitespace, or warning/error messages. Inspect the response in Fiddler to see what the returned content actually is.

Comment: Thanks Dcoder, I checked with Fiddler, but I did not learn anything meaningful from that exercise. I copy-pasted the server-response above.

Comment: Try outputting the headers without checking for `headers_sent`. This will trigger an error saying that headers cannot be sent anymore, and specify the file/line where this garbage output was first started.

Comment: OK, I will do that (outputting without checking headers_sent). In the meanwhile, I intercepted the output with ob_start() & ob_get_contents(). It looks like two newline characters: string(2) "

"

Comment: Ok, got it! DCoder was right: without headers_sent() it shows an error message in Fiddler. It turns out that I had some whitespace in the controller-file. The whitespace got sent to output and created all the trouble.   DCoder, thans a million for your help!